# JsonSchema definition for either or value

Tags: json, jsonschema, helm3

I am writing a JSON schema for helm chart values.yaml wherein the yaml file is as follows:

```
accessID: "" // user set this value when installing individual chart
global:
  accessID: "" // user set this when installing the parent which this chart is part of
```

How can I write JSON schema (version 7) to validate either one of this should have a non empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an `anyOf` wrapped around the checks for either property. Exact matches can be done with `const`.

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#constant-values
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html